# Could RSync be used to backup Parallels vm to KVM?

Tags: rsync

So I am currently using Parallels on my macbook pro but I am wanting to also use them on my desktop, which uses KVM.
Since I don't believe KVM can read the parallels file format, would it be possible for the VM to Rsync its self over to KVM? so they are sort of in sync with each other?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

KVM cannot use parallels images directly, but there is a convertor "qemu-img". You can do it like this: https://vanappdeveloper.com/2013/07/04/converting-parallels-vm-to-linux-kvm/

RSync method will also work. You can either just send the contents of your (linux?) vm to the other system or just use tar to archive and transfer your data.